# Is it possible to interact with an embed movie via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I am embedding a movie in a web page with the embed tag, but I would like to interact and be interacted via javascript with the embedded movie in .mov. In particular, I would like to get the timings so I can perform actions on the web pages when a particular moment in the movie is reached (like adding subtitles or karaoke effects in the page as the movie plays).

Is this possible with standard HTML 4 and javascript, or do I need flash or maybe html 5 ?

Comment: Add the video info to the question.

Comment: Please close out the question by chosing the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You most certainly can do this, I've done this with MOVs on a major project. Refer to [this page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/bQTScripting_JavaScri_Document/QuickTimeandJavaScri.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001526-CH001-SW5) for all you need to know.

Comment: it is a mov video included with the embed tag.

Comment: @Cirrostratus use comments to ask such clarifications.

Comment: I knew I should, however I've never seen how to comment on the question. I can see the comment link for answers, but not the question.

Comment: You will start seeing those from now onwards. You need to have 50 reputation points to comment on others' posts http://stackoverflow.com/faq Btw, why did you make this community wiki?

Comment: I make it a wiki initially in a lame attempt at trying to figure out how to comment on the question :)
At the time, I wasn't aware of the 50-pt rule

Answer (score 1):

*Applies only to embedded flash content - post was made before OP clarified that he was using `mov` files.*

---

Yes it is - provided you have access to the source code of the flash movie. Interaction between Flash movie and the javascript is done through [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#includeExamplesSummary) - check out the `call()` and `addCallback()` methods in that page.

As for getting the timings, you can use [playheadTime](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#playheadTime) property of the video player control. You might also want to check out the cue points - FLV player dispatches [cuePoint events](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#event:cuePoint) when the play head reaches cue points set at the time of creating the FLV.

You can Listen to these events and call appropriate javascript functions using `ExternalInterface`.

Comment: it is a .mov file embedded with the embed tag, it is not flash. it gets visualized through quicktime on my mac, and I assume there can be cross-platform issues to consider